# Imagick incorrect identifyImage() function

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have vertical image (1333px width and 2000px height), it correctly loaded, but when i used:

```
$img->identifyImage();
```

it print:

```
["geometry"] => array(2) {
   ["width"] => int(2000)
   ["height"] => int(1333)
}
```

Can anyone give some advice about why that happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image probably has an orientation set in its EXIF data. Have a look at the `Imagick::getImageOrientation` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageorientation.php).